# How to keep displaying the changeable real-time data in label every second?

Tags: python, kivy, label, ids

In my code, it uses pyaudio to get user's voice pitch and volume.
It keeps showing the numeric values every second in terminal.
[image]

The problem is when I use Stringproperty or ids method to display them in the label, it doesn't show anything.
[image]

But, after the code breaks, then it shows the data which is the last volume and pitch in the label.
[image]

How can I display the real-time data every second in the label?

Here is my sample code .py:

```
while True:
    
        data = stream.read(1024)
        samples = num.fromstring(data,
            dtype=aubio.float_type)
        pitch = pDetection(samples)[0]
        # Compute the energy (volume) of the
        # current frame.
        volume = num.sum(samples**2)/len(samples)
        # Format the volume output so that at most
        # it has six decimal numbers.
        volume = "{:.6f}".format(volume)
        print(pitch)
        print(volume)
        
        #self.ids.pitchs.text= str(pitch)
        self.ids.volumes.text= volume 
        self.pitchs1 = str(pitch) 
      
            
        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):  # if key '1' is pressed 
                break  # finishing the[1] loop
```

here is .kv file:

```
<Genereate>
 GridLayout:
     cols: 1
 GridLayout:
     size: root.width, root.height
     cols:2
     Label:
         id: pitchs
         text: root.pitchs1
         color: 1,0,1,1
    
     Label:
         id: volumes
         text: "Volume"
         color: 1,0,1,1
 Button:
     text: "Submit"
     size_hint: .5, .6
     on_release: root.pitches()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the while loop will run very fast that the User will not note any changes the solution for the is using kivy clock module like following
create a method to deal the calculations

```py
def streaming(self, *args):
    data = stream.read(1024)
    samples = num.fromstring(data,
                             dtype=aubio.float_type)
    pitch = pDetection(samples)[0]
    # Compute the energy (volume) of the
    # current frame.
    volume = num.sum(samples ** 2) / len(samples)
    # Format the volume output so that at most
    # it has six decimal numbers.
    volume = "{:.6f}".format(volume)
    print(pitch)
    print(volume)

    # self.ids.pitchs.text= str(pitch)
    self.ids.volumes.text = volume
    self.pitchs1 = str(pitch
```

and now you should use the clock method to call every one second or any other period

```py
def run_stream(self,):
    schedule=Clock.schedule_interval(streaming, 1)
    # you can stop the steaming like this 
    if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):  # if key '1' is pressed 
        schedule.cancle()
```